# How to Merge Objects from list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm setting some rest api with Flask and I have a list of objects with same name but some fields are different, how can I merge all objects with same name field with other ?

```
servers_list = [{ "name": "server1", 
                  "ip": "192.168.1.1", 
                  "alias": "PRNA" }, 
                { "name": "server1", 
                  "ip": "192.168.1.2", 
                  "alias": "PRNA" }, 
                { "name": "server1", 
                  "ip": "192.168.1.1", 
                  "alias": "SLKE" }]
```

As you can see there is 3 servers with same name but 2 with different ips and 1 with different alias , I expect to get one object:

```
{
  "name": "server1",
  "ip": ["192.168.1.1", "192,168.1.2"],
  "alias": ["PRNA", "SLKE"]
}
```

How can I recieve that with python or pandas ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this with list comprehension and pd.concat:

```
servers_list = [{ "name": "server1", 
                  "ip": "192.168.1.1", 
                  "alias": "PRNA" }, 
                { "name": "server1", 
                  "ip": "192.168.1.2", 
                   "alias": "PRNA" }, 
                { "name": "server1", 
                  "ip": "192.168.1.1", 
                  "alias": "SLKE" }]

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i, index=[0]) for i in servers_list])\
  .groupby('name')\
  .agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())\
  .reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'server1',
  'ip': ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2'],
  'alias': ['PRNA', 'SLKE']}]
```

Comment: @arikbi Thank you.  Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

This will create new merged dictionary.

```
servers_list = [{ "name": "server1", "ip": "192.168.1.1", "alias": "PRNA" }, { "name": "server1", "ip": "192.168.1.2", "alias": "PRNA" }, { "name": "server1", "ip": "192.168.1.1", "alias": "SLKE" }]


dict={}
for ser in servers_list:
    for key in (ser):
        if key in dict:
            if ser[key] not in dict[key]:
                dict[key].append(ser[key])
        else:
            dict[key]=[ser[key]]
print(dict)
```

Comment: I want too add that there is another identical fields and more not identical fields, at final result I want to get an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
merged = dict()

for entry in server_list:
   if entry['name'] not in merged:
       entry['ip'] = [entry['ip']] # convert to list
       merged[entry['name']] = entry
   else: # if name is a duplicate
      merged[entry['name']]['ip'].append(entry['ip']) # add the ip
```

This code merges the IPs, you can extend it to the aliases too.

Answer (score 0):

```
servers_list = [{ "name": "server1", "ip": "192.168.1.1", "alias": "PRNA" }, { "name": "server1", "ip": "192.168.1.2", "alias": "PRNA" }, { "name": "server1", "ip": "192.168.1.1", "alias": "SLKE" }]

import json

def loads(datas):
    ret = {}
    for i in datas:
        if isinstance(i,dict):
            for j in i.keys():
                if j in ret:
                    ret[j].add(i[j])
                else:
                    ret[j] = set( (i[j],) )
        else:
            ret[i]=None
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = loads(servers_list)
    for i in t.keys():
        if isinstance(t[i],set):
            t[i] = list(t[i])
    print(json.dumps(t,indent=4))
```

you can iterate them and put them into a dict object.

Comment: I want too add that there is another identical fields and more not identical fields, at final result I want to get an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = []
for i in range(0, len(servers_list)):
    if servers_list[i].get("merged") != 1:
        item = {"name": servers_list[i].get("name"), "ip": [servers_list[i].get("ip")],
                "alias": [servers_list[i].get("alias")]}
        for j in range(i + 1, len(servers_list)):
            if servers_list[i].get('name') == servers_list[j].get('name'):
                ip = set()
                ip.add(servers_list[j].get('ip'))
                alias = set()
                alias.add(servers_list[j].get('alias'))
                item["ip"] = list(set(item["ip"] + (list(ip))))
                item["alias"] = list(set(item["alias"] + (list(alias))))
                servers_list[j]["merged"] = 1
        new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```